# AWK - Select lines to print according to score

Tags: awk, gawk

I have a tab-separated file containing a series of lemmas with associated scores.
The file contains 5 columns, the first column is the lemma and the third is the one that contains the score. What I need to do is print the line as it is, when lemma is not repeated and print the line with the highest score when lemma is repeated.

IN

```
Lemma    ---    Score    ---    ---
cserép    06a    55    6    bueno
darázs    05     38    1    bueno
dél    06a    34    1    bueno
dér    06a    29    1    bueno
díj    05    14    89    malo
díj    06a    2    101    malo
díj    06b    2    101    malo
díj    07    90    13    bueno
díj    08a    2    101    malo
díj    08b    2    101    malo
egér    06a    66    5    bueno
fonal    05    12    1    bueno
fonal    07    52    4    bueno
```

Desired output

```
Lemma    ---    Score    ---    ---
cserép    06a    55    6    bueno
darázs    05    38    1    bueno
dél    06a    34    1    bueno
dér    06a    29    1    bueno
díj    07    90    13    bueno
egér    06a    66    5    bueno
fonal    07    52    4    malo
```

What I have done. But it only works when the lemma is repeated once.

```
BEGIN {
    OFS=FS="\t";
    flag="";
}
{
    id=$1;

    if (id != flag)
    {
        if (line != "")
        {   
            sub("^;","",line);

            z=split(line,A,";");
            if ((A[3] > A[8]) && (A[8] != ""))
            {
                print A[1]"\t"A[2]"\t"A[3]"\t"A[4]"\t"A[5];
            }
            else if ((A[8] > A[3]) && (A[8] != ""))
            {
                print A[6]"\t"A[7]"\t"A[8]"\t"A[9]"\t"A[10]
            }
            else
            {
                print A[1]"\t"A[2]"\t"A[3]"\t"A[4]"\t"A[5]; 
            }
        }

        delete line;
        flag=id;
    }
    line[$1]=line[$1]";"$2";"$3";"$4";"$5;
}
END {

    line=line ";"$1";"$2";"$3";"$4";"$5
    sub("^;","",line);

    z=split(line,A,";");
    if ((A[3] > A[8]) && (A[8] != ""))
    {
        print A[1]"\t"A[2]"\t"A[3]"\t"A[4]"\t"A[5];
    }
    else if ((A[8] > A[3]) && (A[8] != ""))
    {
        print A[6]"\t"A[7]"\t"A[8]"\t"A[9]"\t"A[10]
    }
    else
    {
        print A[1]"\t"A[2]"\t"A[3]"\t"A[4]"\t"A[5]
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the file sorted by lemma, so that all lines for the same lemma come in one block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested with gnu awk:

```
prevLemma != $1 {
          if( prevLemma ) {
            print line;
          }
          prevLemma = $1;
          prevScore = $3;
          line = $0;
        }
prevLemma == $1 { if( prevScore < $3 )  {
            prevScore = $3;
            line = $0;
          }
        }
END         { print line;}
```

- assumption is: the file is sorted by lemma
- when the lemma changes (or at the very beginning when the var is empty) the lemma, score and line are saved
- when the lemma changes (or in the END), the line for the previous lemma is printed
- when the current line belongs to the same lemma and has a higher score the values are saved again

Comment: Clearly, my logic is very twisty. I have to learn from you.
Your solution works perfectly!.

Comment: Reading and answering here I am also still learning how to apply awk efficiently.

Comment: You don't need to test `prevLemma == $1` since you just set `prevLemma = $1` a couple of lines previously. You don't need all the trailing semi-colons. You shouldn't test `prevLemma` on its own as that would fail if it evaluated to zero numerically - you could test for `prevLemma!=""` or `NR>1` instead.

Answer (score 2):

This one doesn't require the file to be sorted by lemma, *but*, it keeps all the lines to be printed in memory (one for each lemma) so may not be appropriate for a file with millions of different lemmas.

It also does not respect the order of the original file.

Finally, it assumes that all scores are non-negative!

```
$ cat lemma.awk
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" }
NR == 1 { print }
NR > 1 {
    if ($3 > score[$1]) {
        score[$1] = $3
        line[$1] = $0
    }
}
END { for (lemma in line) print line[lemma] }


$ awk -f lemma.awk lemma.txt
Lemma   --- Score   --- ---
cserép  06a   55    6   bueno
díj     07    90    13  bueno
fonal   07    52    4   bueno
darázs  05    38    1   bueno
egér    06a   66    5   bueno
dél     06a   34    1   bueno
dér     06a   29    1   bueno
```

Comment: That's why my script deletes the array each time lemma changes. I like your solution too

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
$1 != prev { printf "%s", maxLine; maxLine=""; max=$3; prev=$1 }
$3 >= max  { max=$3; maxLine=$0 ORS }
END  { printf "%s", maxLine }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Lemma    ---    Score    ---    ---
cserép    06a    55    6    bueno
darázs    05     38    1    bueno
dél    06a    34    1    bueno
dér    06a    29    1    bueno
díj    07    90    13    bueno
egér    06a    66    5    bueno
fonal    07    52    4    bueno
```

Answer (score -2):

Use a script:

```
if ($1 != $5) print $0
else 
  {
  score($NR) = $3
  print $0
  }
```

Actually , this might be better done with perl.

Comment: perl has sort built in, with **awk** you would have to write a routine, quite simple in this case.

Comment: gnu awk has sort built in and you don't need/want sort for this anyway.